# Jquery: Behaviour of multiple ajax calls to same URL

Tags: jquery, ajax

I came across some suprising behaviour today, and wanted to confirm that this is normal for jquery, and not be doing something daft...

I have a function which makes an ajax call and does something on the promise.done().  Below is a simplified example which serves the same purpose.

```
function getRandom() {
    console.log('calling');
    var promise = $.ajax({
        url: '/getrandom/',
        type: 'GET'
    });
    promise.done(function (data) {
        console.log('got ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });
}
```

For the purposes of this question assume that the server will respond with a random number generated on each request.

If I call this function *fast enough so that multiple calls are open before the first response*, then I get output like this:

```
calling
calling
calling
got {num:3452345}
got {num:3452345}
got {num:3452345}
calling
calling
calling
got {num:2342342}
got {num:2342342}
got {num:2342342}
```

This was quite suprising to me, as it suggests that somehow the promise (or some mechinaism internal to jquery) is being overwritten.

**Is this normal expected behaviour?**

Thanks

[jQuery v 1.8.2]

Comment: It looks like the code generating your random number at `/getrandom/` needs to be reseeded on each request. Failing that, you need to turn off caching of the request, with the `cache: false` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try with `cache:false`?

see [Ajax Jquery Api Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Your browser will cache Ajax when doing GET queries. You should check if your server receive 1 query instead of three too.

Comment: Yep, that was it, doh! Note to self: RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, this result is cached. Try to use ajax "cache: false;" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Add querystring with random char or use timestemp see example

```
getrandom?t=xyzrandom
```